# .htaccess 302 code gives a 500-error code

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-500

I added a .htaccess file into a directory, after that, the whole directory became inaccessible with 500 error.

This is my code:

**.htaccess**

```
Redirect 302 /something_here.pdf https://my-domain.tld/something/there/hello-hi.html
```

Comment: Read the apache error log.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I wanted to read, but my web host didn't let me to read(there is no option to read). I turned on the `php_value display_errors On` but nothing is changing.

Comment: I think I should do this with my CDN.

Comment: Nothing flagrantly wrong here.  What is the **exact** address you test with?  FYI if your hosting service does not provide you with your logs, get the ****** out of there!  The ones I know about allow you to FTP into some admin site to download raw log files.